# helm does not create custom resource definition for Azure k8s

Tags: azure, kubernetes-helm, lets-encrypt, azure-aks

I am trying to install letsencrypt with helm.
i tried using helm with this few days before and it works successfully well with my earlier installation.

i used following approach

*helm install with **createcustoresource=false***

```
helm install --name cert-manager --namespace kube-system --set createCustomResource=false --set rbac.create=true stable/cert-manager --set ingressShim.extraArgs='{--default-issuer-name=letsencrypt-prod,--default-issuer-kind=ClusterIssuer}'
```

in logs it clearly indicates that it does not create  custom resources like certificates,clusterissuer,issuers

when i executed following command( with createCustomResource=true )i expect helm should create These custom issuers not created earlier.

```
helm upgrade --install --namespace kube-system cert-manager stable/cert-manager --set createCustomResource=true --set rbac.create=true --set ingressShim.extraArgs='{--default-issuer-name=letsencrypt-prod,--default-issuer-kind=ClusterIssuer}'
```

not sure if i am missing something

Comment: it should, you sure it doesnt? at worst you can do `helm delete cert-manager --purge` and recreate

Comment: I did it but still it is not able to create custom resources

Comment: after deleting? ok try this: `helm upgrade cert-manager --install --namespace kube-system stable/cert-manager --set createCustomResource=true,rbac.create=true --version 0.4.0`. this is working for me no problems

Comment: thanks with additional version parameter i can able to create custom resources but my ultimate aim is to create certificates with webhook.         _helm upgrade --install --version 0.4.0 --namespace kube-system cert-manager stable/cert-manager --set createCustomResource=true --set rbac.create=true --set ingressShim.extraArgs='{--default-issuer-name=letsencrypt-prod,--default-issuer-kind=ClusterIssuer}' **--set webhook.enabled=true**_              again i am unable to see my certificate in secret with kubectl describe secret mycertificate-fordomain-tls

Comment: well, i assume thats a different issue. i put version in the command just because i copy pasted it, you can amend it\exclude it

Comment: then i dont think whatever command i used and one you provided has some significant difference

Comment: mhm, not sure I understand, I've showed you how to create custom resources. i guess that settles this question

Comment: did this answer help you? in case it did - consider accepting\upvoting it

Answer (score 0):

custom resources can be creating using helm with this command:

```
helm upgrade cert-manager --install --namespace kube-system stable/cert-manager --set createCustomResource=true,rbac.create=true --version 0.4.0
```